# I am getting error ssh exit staus 1

Tags: ssh, jenkins

In jenkins post build action I configured *Execute shell script* on remote host using ssh
ssh site *10.32.25.66*, command:

```
cd $HOME/appsadm/bin; ./ims-carte-stop
```

and i again modified

```
cd /HOME/appsadm/bin; ./ims-carte-stop.*
```

I tried both these commands and Build is successful, but I see in console output in Jenkins after, that it is not executing my script. I am getting ssh exit status 1 error.
In my winscp my script (ims-carte-stop) in this location `home/appsadm/bin`.

Please tell me if I am doing aything wrong.
My intention is to stop my server from jenkins automatically whenever the build success.

Comment: Please add relevant part of the console output to the question. Also, can you run the ssh command from command line?

Comment: Also, please check my edits to the question, to be sure I did not change the intended meaning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a typo in your question, but:

You said your `ims-carte-stop` script is in:

```
/home/appsadm/bin
```

whereas your script is doing:

```
cd $HOME/appsadm/bin
or
cd /HOME/appsadm/bin
```

Looking at the paths, I am going to assume you are using a UNIX-flavoured OS (Linux, BSD, OSX).
UNIX paths are case sensitive. Your script should be calling:

```
cd /home/appsadm/bin
```

Note that the word "home" is all small letter not capitals. Also, using `$` makes it a variable, which I don't think you want.